# How to delete answered inline query when pressing the InlineKeyboardButton? (python-telegram-bot)

Tags: python-telegram-bot

In a nutshell, I want to add "Cancel" button into InlineKeyboardMarkup. But I have problems when adding it when using inline mode.

I want to delete a message created by InlineQueryResultArticle in InlineQueryHandler's function. I'm passing reply_markup with some InlineKeyboardButtons. The last button has text='Cancel' and callback_data that is an object of my custom class CancelMessage() (I don't think the problem is related to this class).

In main function there is `CallbackQueryHandler(cancel, pattern=CancelMessage)` and
`InlineQueryHandler(post_issue_inline)`

Logger says that `update.effective_chat` and `update.message` are both `None`, thus, I can't use `context.bot.delete_message()`. Possible reason that I think I can't delete message is because

1. when I type @bot's_username in telegram app, the text I'm typing pops up, then I push/choose it, then the message (that I want to delete) with buttons is sent **by me, not by bot**
2. this leads to `None` type of `update.message` (and maybe `update.effective_chat`)
3. -> I can't delete this message.

I've tried a lot of variants of deleting. I was only able to edit the text of this message by `update.callback_query.edit_message_text('some text')`

```
def cancel(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    context.bot.delete_message(update.effective_chat.id, update.callback_query.message.message_id) # doesn't work

def post_issue_inline(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    query = update.inline_query.query
    if query != '':
        if '.' in query:
            summary = query[:query.find('.')].strip()
            description = query[query.find('.'):].strip()
        else:
            summary = query
            description = ''
        project = SetProjectMessage(summary, description)
        names_ids = projects_name_id(update, context, project)
        article = InlineQueryResultArticle(
            id=str(uuid4()),
            title=query,
            input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(query),
            reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(make_keyboard(names_ids, extra_buttons=1))
        )
        update.inline_query.answer([article])
```

Function `projects_name_id(...)` returns me a list of tuples `[(to_text, to_callback_data), ...]` from which I `make_keyboard()` with `InlineKeyboardButton`s

I found that I can delete message if it was sent by bot. How can I send message with reply_markup (that was in `InlineQueryResultArticle`) **by bot** in post_issue_inline?

Comment: use message.Delete_inline_request()

Comment: @Rohithaditya I can't find this method, could you please share where can I read? And what ```message``` did you meant about?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the bot may not be part of the chat where the message is sent. E.g. you can use `@botusername …` in a private chat with another person. In these cases, the bot can't possibly be allowed to delete messages of chats that it's not even a member of. This is probably the reason whay [`deleteMessage`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage) does not accept an `inline_message_id` (in contrast to `edit_message_text`).

Note that even in cases where the bot *is* a member of the chat where the message is sent, `update.callback_query.message` will still be `None`.